# How does javascript handle undefined comparators within for loops?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, undefined

I recently fell victim to what I thought was an infinite for-loop in javascript, due to the following code.

```
//Mongoose Schema, defined elsewhere
var foo  = new Schema({
        _id: Number,
         a: [ Number ],
         b: [ Number ] });
```

...

```
//loop code, running on node.js server

Foo.findOne({}, 'b').exec().then(function(result)
{
 if(result)
 {
 for(var i = 0; i < result['a'].length; i++)
    {
     ...  
     //oops, we used the wrong property!
    }
 console.log("This line is never reached!");
 }
}
```

Because foo doesn't have property `bar`, foo['bar'] is undefined, and the comparator never returns true (and ending the loop).

But what surprises me most about this code, is that it doesn't *crash*. So I was curious - did comparing a number to `undefined` always equal true? Because the program loops infinitely, I know the comparison doesn't return false.

In an attempt to test, I swapped the less than to a greater than, but I still never reached the console output. So what is going on? Why does this not cause a runtime error, and what, actually is getting compared?

Comment: Afaik `n < undefined` always returns `false`, despite of value of `n`. Which browser you've tested? Probably no infinite loop, just an error stopping the execution...

Comment: From that code I'm only getting an exception "cannot access `length` property on `undefined` (`foo.bar`)", which leads to the line never to be reached. No infinite loop. Please provide an example code that actually exhibits the outlined behaviour…

Comment: "TypeError: foo.bar is undefined" is the error I get

Comment: Hm. Maybe my situation was more complicated than I thought. This is on a Node.js server that is accessing the result of a Mongo database via a Mongoose.js call. I will see if I can get a better picture of the code, but I'm not sure if I can deliver something like a jsfiddle that *just runs*.

Comment: Code updated as per request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, if the `foo` object doesn't have a `bar` property, it will throw a `TypeError`, because you are trying to access a property of an undefined variable. This should halt the script execution.

```
var a;

a.length; //TypeError: a is undefined
```

Also, I made some tests and comparing undefined to a number using the `<` operator always returns false.

```
0 < undefined; //false
1 < undefined; //false
```

Following this logic, the following shouldn't loop and that's what happens in my case:

```
var o = {};

for (var i = 0; i < o.length; i++) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

Perhaps your assumptions are wrong?

Comment: This.  I copied/pasted the original poster's code into the JS console and it indeed throws a TypeError.

Comment: For what it's worth, I have altered the original code provided. I think it is something specific to how Mongo handles things, and perhaps not an issue with the underlying JS.

Comment: @RavenDreamer, Have you tried my examples straight in NodeJS to see if it's handled differently? Also, can you assert that `result['a'].length` returns `undefined`?

Comment: @plalx I can assert that result['a'] returns undefined. Doing console.log(result['a'].length) did not output *anything*. (Though no errors, either).

Comment: @RavenDreamer: Then there must be something in your app that catches the exception (triggerd either in the loop comparison or from your log attempt) without outputting anything but silently restarting. Do you know of such code?

Comment: @Bergi Come to think of it, that code bloc is inside a Mongoose promise. That might be the cause of the code failing silently. If that's true, then this entire question is sort of moot, I suppose.

Comment: @RavenDreamer: Did you attach a fail handler to the promise, or use [`.end()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#promise_Promise-end)?

Comment: @Bergi I did not, which is why it would be failing "silently". Lesson learned, I suppose.